# What purpose does `gsl::string_span` aim at?

Tags: c++, c++11, library-design, cpp-core-guidelines

During reading [Microsoft's implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) of [Cpp Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), I run across two questions:

1. Why is `gsl::string_span` provided where `gsl::span` already works well?
2. Why is `gsl::zstring_span` provided where `std::string` is already guaranteed to be null-terminated since C++11?

Any illustrating situations will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read [the comments above `basic_zstring_span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/string_span#L379)?

Comment: I've read the comment you cited. However, I'm still unclear.

Comment: @szxwpmj What about the comment do you understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `span("Hi")` is `{'H', 'i', '\0'}` whereas `string_span("Hi")` is `{'H', 'i'}`. `string_span` checks for the terminating null character and does not include it in the span.
2. `string` is owning and spans are not, so comparing them is comparing apples and oranges. `zstring_span` is a span with the constraint that the last character is a null character. Neither `span` nor `string_span` have that constraint.