# How do gsl::string_span and std::string_view differ?

Tags: string-view, guideline-support-library, string-span

From what I can gather, `gsl::string_span` and `std::string_view` seem to have essentially the same rationale for use. Is that indeed the case? If so, are they effectively identical? If not - how do they differ?

Related question: [What purpose does `gsl::string_span` aim at?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348933/what-purpose-does-gslstring-span-aim-at)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do `gsl::string_span` and `std::string_view` differ?

A rather obvious difference of how they are available, but I'll say it since it is significant: `gsl::string_span` requires the use of a third party library, while `std::string_view` is a standard C++ type. On the other hand, the library providing `gsl::string_span` supports C++14, while  `std::string_view` requires C++17.

A major design difference is that `std::string_view` is a const view to the string, and doesn't provide any way of modifying the viewed string, while `gsl::string_span` does allow non-const access. For example:

```
constexpr iterator gsl::string_span::begin() const noexcept
          ^^^^^^^^ note non-const iterator   ^^^^^ also note this
```

Also note how `gsl::string_span` allows non-const access even when the span itself is const. in other words, `gsl::string_span` does not propagate constness. This is the same as `std::span` and `gsl::span`.

Comment: Shouldn't `gsl::string_view` have been an endeavor to mimic the coming `std::string_view`? How come they diverged on something as significant as deep vs shallow constness?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't know; Should it have been? I don't know their rationale. I found a rationale for non-mutability of `std::string_view` here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3762.html#mutable

Comment: In A Tour of C++, 2nd ed., 2018, subsection 9.5, Bjarne Stroustrup says “Use string_view as an argument of functions that needs to read character sequences stored in various ways; Use gsl::string_span as an argument of functions that needs to write character sequences stored in various ways”. So we use gsl::string_span for 2 major reasons: 1. It does what std::string_view does and can be used in C++14 which is a version in which many production code is (obviously more than C++17); 2. It allows us to modify the content of the string, a thing that std::string_view doesn’t.